# Switching nodes in High Availability mode

Tags: high-availability, dolphindb

I repeatedly switch data nodes in high availability mode, the terminal continues prompting that the transaction is occupied, and then resumes after a few minutes. Why does this occur?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the questions about switching data nodes repeatedly, prompting the transactions are occupied and so on, the mechanism is as follows. After a data node is down, it takes some time to synchronize the transaction status between itself and the control node. The transaction timeout is about two minutes. In addition, There is some time spent on data recovery, which is related to the specific data volume. If you switch back to this node again in a short time, you will be prompted that the transaction is occupied, and it will be restored in about two minutes. In actual production, the probability of a node breaks down, especially some different nodes hangs continuously within a few minutes is extremely small. Thus, for high-availability tests, it is recommended to set the interval between simulated hangs more than two minutes. It is better to have interval time longer than 5 mins for simulating the breakdown of next node.